# Tabulator dropdown disappear its own instantly in Tablet/mobile view

Tags: javascript, php

Its work fine on PC, but on a tablet, when I click on the dropdown, it opens along with the virtual keyboard, and the dropdown and virtual keyboard disappear instantly. I think the problem would be solved if the virtual keyboard didn't open/close on its own.

I want to open the dropdown and ensure that it remains open until I take any action. It should not close on its own.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accrodingly.